# Exporting selenium scraped data to CSV file?

Tags: python, selenium, csv

In the following script, I scraped the coronavirus data from a table on worldometers.info/coronavirua with selenium.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

class CoronaBot():
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def scraper(self):
    self.driver.get('https://worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
    main_table = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_table_countries_today"]')
    country = main_table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'Austria')]")
    row = country.find_element_by_xpath("./..")
    data = row.text.split(" ")
    total_cases = data[0]
    new_cases = data[1]
    total_deaths = data[2]
    new_deaths = data[3]
    active_cases = data[4]
    total_recovered = data[5]
    serious_critical = data[6]
```

The code works fine, I could just print it out like this:

```
    print("COVID-19 updates in: " + country.text)
    print("Total Cases: " + total_cases)
    ...
```

However, I want to take the output of the scraped results and place it in a new csv file (the csv file needs to be created when the script is run.)

I tried something stupid like this in panda, but it obviously did not work. Any suggestion?

```
def create_csv(self):

    collected_data = []

    collected_data.append(output)

    df = pd.DataFrame(collected_data, columns=['total_cases', 'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 
    'new_deaths', 'active_cases', 'total_recovered','serious_critical'])
    df.to_csv('scraped_corona.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is a great solution, you were close. In your example, you can just use the scraper function to put data in the data frame right away.

At first, I'd create `self.df` attribute to store the data frame:

```py
class CoronaBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        column_names = ['total_cases', 'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 'new_deaths','active_cases', 'total_recovered', 'serious_critical']
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Then, after you collect the data, store it in `self.df`:

```py
...
print("Total recovered: " + total_recovered)
print("Serious, critical cases: " + serious_critical)

self.df = self.df.append(
    {'total_cases': total_cases,
     'new_cases': new_cases,
     'total_deaths': total_deaths,
     'new_deaths': new_deaths,
     'active_cases': active_cases,
     'total_recovered': total_recovered,
     'serious_critical': serious_critical}, ignore_index=True)
```

And add a function for exporting:

```
    def export_to_csv(self):
        self.df.to_csv('scraped_corona.csv')
```

Now, when I run

```
c = CoronaBot()
c.scraper()
c.export_to_csv()
```

I get the .csv file.
Hope it helps, good luck!